# How to split a tensorflow dataset into N datasets with shuffling

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensorflow dataset`ds` and I would like to split it into N datasets whose union is the original dataset and that do not share samples among them.
I tried:

```
ds_list = [ds.shard(N,index=i) for i in range(N)]
```

But unfortunately it's not random: each new dataset will always get the same samples from the original dataset. For instance, ds_list[0] will have samples number 0,N,2N,3N..., while ds_list[1] will have 1,N+1,2N+1,3N+1...
Is there any way to have a random subdivision of the original dataset into datasets of the same size?

Unfortunately simply shuffling before won't solve the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import math

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])

N=2
ds = ds.shuffle(20)
ds_list = [ds.shard(N,index=i) for i in range(N)]


for ds in ds_list:
    shard_set = sorted(set(list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())))
    print(shard_set)
```

Output:

```
    [3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 14, 15, 19, 20]
    [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15, 20]
```

Same as:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
N=2
ds_list = []
ds = ds.shuffle(20)
size = ds.__len__()
sub = math.floor(size/N)
for n in range(N):
    ds_sub = ds.take(sub)
    remainder = ds.skip(sub)
    ds_list.append(ds_sub)
    ds = remainder  

for ds in ds_list:
    shard_set = sorted(set(list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())))
    print(shard_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first shuffle the dataset and then shard it:

```
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size)
ds_list = [ds.shard(N,index=i) for i in range(N)]
```

Here `buffer_size` is the size of buffer used by TF for sorting. If size of dataset is small, you can pass total number of examples as `buffer_size`. Otherwise a smaller number (anything like 100), which can fit into memory, will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution that you proposed does not work because it doesn't guarantee that all the samples are in one and only one "split" dataset

Comment: I think it does because shuffle doesn't consider same example multiple times (as you are not repeating the dataset). Can you provide an example which shoes that same example is coming in multiple splits?
If you use repeat before shuffle, then what you are saying makes sense but as that's not happening here, I think this should work.

Comment: Hi, here's a possible code to visually test it. There are some samples that are in both datasets and some that are not. I edited the main question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (for N shards):

```
ds_list = []
ds = ds.shuffle()
size = ds.__len__()
sub = floor(size/N)
for n in range(N):
    ds_sub = ds.take(sub)
    remainder = ds.skip(sub)
    ds_list.append(ds_sub)
    ds = remainder
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution that you proposed does not work because it doesn't guarantee that all the samples are in one and only one "split" dataset

Comment: I believe it does since at the end of the loop ds is set to the remainder. So the points added to ds_sub are never considered again.

Comment: I guess that it's because of the shuffling, since the take and skip operation could involve samples in different order. Feel free to use the code I provided in the main question.

Comment: No the shuffle happens before. Then you keep taking and skipping until all the data is assigned.

Comment: Have you tested your code? Just try the code I provided into the main question. You'll see that you will get shards that share some samples